# How to assign key and count to two different labels asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have this query:

```
var months = dates.GroupBy(
      x => x.Value.Month).Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});
lbl1.Text = string.Join(",", months);
```

How do I assign key and count to two different labels?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If you want to get a comma delimited list of months in dates, then it would be `lbl1.Text = string.Join(",", months.Select(m => m.Month));`

Comment: where are the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
lblMonth.Text=months.Month;
lblCount.Text=months.Count;
```

Also you have to call `FirstOrDefault()` or `ToList()` in order to select data. Currently you code will not select data.

```
var months = dates.GroupBy(x => x.Value.Month).Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).FirstOrDefault();
```

OR

```
var months = dates.GroupBy(x => x.Value.Month).Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

if you use `ToList()` than you will have to get values by index like

```
lblMonth.Text=months[0].Month;
lblCount.Text=months[0].Count;
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault() will only take the first value. i want to take all the values like ToList(); but this is not working.